# Refferal Program in Flutter(IOS)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm developing a mobile app in Flutter and I implemented a referral program. In Android, I get the referral code by using the plugin but in IOS I was not able to apply the referral program. Now I want that I need to get a reference code from Share for IOS in Flutter. If anybody implemented the referral program in IOS on Flutter, Kindly share the procedure with me.
Advance thanks.